# How do I enable control-left and control-right to switch between open tabs in Vim when running Iterm2?

Tags: vi, iterm2

When using Vi in Iterm2 on OSx, how can I switch between open tabs using control+left to navigate to the left, and control+right to navigate to the right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default OSx keyboard is hijacking this for mission control. disable this in Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts. uncheck Mission Control

Next, Iterm2 is hijacking this key combination. Go to Iterm2 Preferences > Profiles > Keys > Default > Load Preset and select xterm Defaults

consider using recursive map with remap. in the vimrc.after

`noremap <C-Left> :tabprevious<cr>
noremap <C-Right> :tabnext<cr>`

Answer (score 0):

If your version of vi supports key mappings,
You can use them.

```
    :map <C-Left> :tabprevious
    :map <C-Right> :tabnext
```

If you use vim, you can put this in ~/.vimrc.